# document.getElementById only applies to one product

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So basically, when I click on the `addToBasket` button, the `document.getElementById()` only works for the first product. Even when clicking on a different product, it always changes the first one.

How can I prevent that from happening?

I want to display the remove button on the product that I want click on.

```
function Product(/* ... */) {
    const addToBasket = () => { 
        // DISPATCH ITEM INTO THE DATA LAYER
        dispatch({ 
            type: "ADD_TO_BASKET", 
            item: { 
                id: id, 
                title: title, 
                image: image, 
                price: price, 
                rating: rating, 
            } 
        }) 
    }  
 
    const addToBasketFull = () => {
        if(user){
            addToBasket()
            document.getElementById('addButton').style.display="none"
            document.getElementById('removeButton').style.display ='block'
        } else {
            alert('You need to be Signed-In in order to add products to the Basket.')
        };
    }

    return (
        <div className="product">
            <div className="product__info">
                <p className="product__title">{title}</p>
                <p className="product__price">
                    <strong>${price}</strong>
                </p>
                <div className="product__rating">
                    {Array(rating)
                    .fill()
                    .map(() => (
                        <StarIcon />
                    ))}
                </div>
            </div>

            <img src={image}/>
            <button id="addButton" className="product__buttonAdd" onClick={addToBasketFull}>Add to Basket</button>
            <button id="removeButton" className="product__buttonRemove" onClick={''}>Remove from Basket</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Product
```

Comment: In React you shouldn't use DOM methods unless strictly necessary. You can express what you need with React state.

Comment: Also keep in mind that IDs must be unique within the document. So basically your component is only usable once per entire app.

Comment: Your are likely setting identical IDs to multiple elements, which is invalid in HTML. The function name is clear on this too: `getElementById`, not `getElementsById`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use React state, not DOM manipulation:

```
function Product(/* ... */) {
    const [isInBasket, setInBasket] = useState(false);

    // ...
 
    const addToBasketFull = () => {
        if(user){
            addToBasket()
            setInBasket(true);
        } else {
            alert('You need to be Signed-In in order to add products to the Basket.')
        };
    }

    return (
      { /* ... */ }
            <button
              style={{ display: isInBasket ? 'none' : 'block' }} 
              className="product__buttonAdd"
              onClick={addToBasketFull}
            >
              Add to Basket
            </button>
            <button
              style={{ display: isInBasket ? 'block' : 'none' }}
              className="product__buttonRemove"
            >
              Remove from Basket
            </button>
      { /* ... */ }
    )
}
```

This is important because with React managing the creation of DOM elements, any manual changes you make to the DOM might be undone at any time if React generates new DOM elements.

Comment: it says ×TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null   how can i fix that

Comment: Sounds like you're still doing some `getElementById`, then.

Comment: my bad i didnt see it, fixed it, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById` will only select the first matching element if you have declared multiple ids.

Note that `id` attribute should carry unique value for each element. If you have multiple elements with `addButton` and `removeButton` ids then only first one will work

A Demo:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('same').innerText);
console.log(document.getElementById('unique').innerText);
```

```html
<div id="same">First Text</div>
<div id="same"> second Text</div>

<div id="unique">Some Text</div>
```

I will suggest passing a value representing an object/id of the product to add/removeButton and then processing based on that:

```html
<button id="addButton" 
        className="product__buttonAdd" 
        onClick={ () => this.addToBasketFull(productId) }>
            Add to Basket
</button>
```